# How to add doctype in XML document using DOM

Tags: java, xml, dom, doctype

I have created a XML document using DOM in Java. I am unable to add doctype. I want the doctype like this.

```xml
<!DOCTYPE IndInfo PUBLIC "EDAFileSomething" "EDAFileSomething_2_0.dtd">
```

Here is the document creation code.

```java
DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();
```

Here is the Transformer object code.

```java
TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = null;
try {
    transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
} catch (TransformerConfigurationException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(Reader.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
try {

    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);
    transformer.transform(source, result);
} catch (TransformerException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(Reader.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}

System.out.println("File saved!");
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can construct the doctype with the DOM and set the doctype as an output property.

```
TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "no");
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
DOMImplementation domImpl = document.getImplementation();
DocumentType doctype = domImpl.createDocumentType("doctype",
    "-//Oberon//YOUR PUBLIC DOCTYPE//EN",
    "YOURDTD.dtd");
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.DOCTYPE_PUBLIC, doctype.getPublicId());
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.DOCTYPE_SYSTEM, doctype.getSystemId());
DOMSource source = new DOMSource(document);
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File(database));
transformer.transform(source, result);
```

Comment: What's the version and package for Document here?  There is no getImplementation() in my version.

Comment: getImplementation() is for the DocumentBuilder object docBuilder

Comment: Very useful information, but what's the point of the separate step of creating a `DocumentType` object? If you're just setting output properties of the `Transformer`, can't you just skip that step and set the strings directly? It would appear in your example that the actual `DocumentType` instance is not needed.

Comment: I wanted to add that you can also simply add `transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.DOCTYPE_SYSTEM, "standardX05.dtd");` instead of the additional steps though both are valid approaches.

Answer (score 1):

If you get an instance of  `DOMImplementation` by invoking the `getDOMImplementation()` method on the `DocumentBuilder`, you can use the `createDocument` method to create a new `Document` with the specified doctype.

It also has a `createDocumentType` method for creating a `DocumentType` object

Refer to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/DOMImplementation.html and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.html  for more info.