# How to add a doctype signature use org.w3c.dom.document

Tags: java

I am using org.w3c.dom.document to create an XML file. The document object or element object do not have setDoctype() method. How to create an element with '!doctype' and dtd? Like this:

[image: roottag with doctype]

Then create a xml file like below code.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE configuration
PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Config 3.0//EN"
"http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-config.dtd">
<configuration>
<environments default="development">
<environment id="development">
<transactionManager type="JDBC"/>
<dataSource type="POOLED">
<property name="driver" value="${driver}"/>
<property name="url" value="${url}"/>
<property name="username" value="${username}"/>
<property name="password" value="${password}"/>
</dataSource>
</environment>
</environments>
<mappers>
<mapper resource="org/mybatis/example/BlogMapper.xml"/>
</mappers>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't add it to the document object. It is added when constructing XML from DOM.

```java
DOMImplementation domImpl = document.getImplementation();
DocumentType doctype = domImpl.createDocumentType("doctype",
    "-//Oberon//YOUR PUBLIC DOCTYPE//EN",
    "YOURDTD.dtd");
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.DOCTYPE_PUBLIC, doctype.getPublicId());
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.DOCTYPE_SYSTEM, doctype.getSystemId());
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23688424/2158271) for more information.